# ipv6 loopback interface ( ::1/128 )

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ipv6, ipsec

What could be the reason for loopback interface ( ::1/128 ) not getting added on the routing table?
I am using command to check : "route -n inet6 -A"

Sometimes, there is no entry for the loopback interface. 
Please note : ipv6 is enabled.

Comment: What if you do `route -nA inet6` or `netstat -rn --inet6` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I am not asking about the different command options. I want to know, incase loopback interface fails to initialize, we get an error in the kernel log - **init loopback: add_dev failed** . So what could be the reason of this failure (from linux kernel perspective) ?

Answer (score 2):

It's in a different table. Try

```
ip -6 route show table local
```

In Linux, there are three different routing tables by default. In normal usage almost everything is found in the `main` table (Aadditional tables are usually only useful for things like policy routing), but Linux itself does make use of the `local` table for internal/built-in routes.